# how can I showDialog on an onTap

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show a dialog on my flutter app when the `onTap` is triggered.

sample of my code:

```
 hintText: "Mot de passe",
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.lock,
                                color: Color(0xfff28800),
                              ),
                              //hide/show
                              suffixIcon: InkWell(
                                onTap: _togglePasswordVew,
                                child: Icon(Icons.visibility_off, color: Colors.grey,),
                                
                                )
```

I want to test the `Icons.visibility_off` with a `show0Dialog` message

Comment: Can you give more detail about the question?

Comment: i have a problem with password Icons.visibility_off, it didn't work and i want to test my code and knew where is the problem so i think to try adding a showDialoge to the icon (in the on tap) and see if it's work or not.

Comment: by the way, you have to add your boolean value to your obscure parameter on your textfield to see the result

Answer (score 1):

you can use like

```dart
suffixIcon: InkWell(
  onTap: () async {
    _togglePasswordVew();
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(...);
      },
    );
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetX package, and make a function returns the dialog.

Like this:

```
openDialog(){
    Get.defaultDialog(
      title: 'Some message',
      actions: [
        Row(
          children: [
            MaterialButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('Ok'),),
            MaterialButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('Cancel'),),
          ]
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

And in your ui code you can do like this:

```
Getbuilder<ControllerClass>(
  buileder: (controller) => hintText: "Mot de passe",
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.lock,
                                color: Color(0xfff28800),
                              ),
                              //hide/show
                              suffixIcon: InkWell(
                                onTap: controller.openDialog(),
                                child: Icon(Icons.visibility_off, color: Colors.grey,),),
),
```

Comment: try without getx, it will better

Comment: It depends on how you do your manageStates..